# Three brown wires on a 2-way light switch

Tags: wiring, switch, light

I am trying to install a new 2-way light switch with 4 connectors in the rear: two L1 and two COM, as seen here:
[image]

The previous installation looks like this:
[image]
Which is something I had never seen before; I would expect two brown and two blue wires, if anything. But never three brown ones.

Given the context (to add more to it, I'm in Europe), what's the way to proceed and connect them?

Comment: Guessing you did not take a before picture showing the wires connected.  Guessing it is two hots connected together or two switch hots/live together.  With the wires disconnected,  Is something else in the room/house not working?

Comment: Guessing right, unfortunately. These wires are just for the switch in the bathroom, so the rest of the lights at home work normal.

Comment: Have you checked the receptacles/outlets?  One switch and one light just need two wires.  Power to the switch and to an outlet need an extra wire, as does two lights from the switch(but usually it is light to light).

Comment: The yellow/green wire should be your ground/earth.  it should only be connected to an earth symbol or metal housing, not to any other different coloured wires.  I think, but you need to confirm that brown is live and blue is neutral.  A switch should only need live wires.